# Unable to locate runnable browser in Docker container

Tags: docker, containers, jupyter-notebook

While trying to run **ipython notebook** command inside docker container, the following error happens:
 No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.

p.s. I'm using jupyter/all-spark-notebook:4.0 image

```
$ sudo docker run -it -p 8888:8888 jupyter/all-spark-notebook:4.0 ipython notebook

Writing notebook server cookie secret to /.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/jovyan/work
0 active kernels 
The IPython Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to   skip confirmation).
No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an old thread now, but if anyone else is looking for the solution- this is the command I ran.

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8888:8888 jupyter/all-spark-notebook:4.0 ipython notebook --port=8888 --ip=0.0.0.0
```

and after that you would go the docker's ip address (windows- `192.168.99.100:8888`, *nix- `"whatever the the ip of your server":8888`) instead of localhost.